# Matlab: Efficiently generating auditory spikes

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to generate a series of "auditory spikes" from a sampled signal in MATLAB, and the method I have so far implemented is slow. Too slow.

The spikes are generated a la section II, B of http://patrec.cs.tu-dortmund.de/pubs/papers/Plinge2010-RNF.pdf : detect the zero crossings and sum the (square-root compressed) positive parts of the signal between each pair. This gives the height of each spike. Their positions are found by identifying the sample with the maximum value between each pair of zero crossings.

I thought of using accumarray(...) for this, which led me to the idea of generating a matrix where each column represents a pair of zero crossings (a spike) and each row a sample. Each column is then filled in with ones between the corresponding pair of zero crossings.

The current implementation fills these columns in from the actual data vector, so that we do not have to use accumarray afterwards.

Current implementation:

```
function out = audspike(data)
    % Find the indices of the zero crossings. Two types of zero crossing:
    %   * Exact, samples where data == 0
    %   * Change, where data(i) .* data(i+1) < 0; that is, data changes sign
    %   between two samples. In this implementation i+1 is returned as the
    %   index of the zero crossing.
    zExact = (data == 0);
    zChange = logical([0; data(1:end-1) .* data(2:end) < 0]);
    zeroInds = find(zExact | zChange);

    % Vector of the difference between each zero crossing index
    z=[zeroInds(1)-1; diff(zeroInds)];

    % Find the "number of zeros" it takes to move from the first sample to the 
    % a given zero crossing
    nzeros=cumsum(z);

    % If the first sample is positive, we cannot generate a spike for the first
    % pair of zero crossings as this represents part of the signal that is
    % negative; therefore, skip the first zero crossing and begin pairing from
    % the second
    if data(1) > 0
        nzeros = nzeros(2:2:end);
        nones = z(3:2:end)+1;
    else
        nzeros = nzeros(1:2:end);
        nones = z(2:2:end)+1;
    end

    % Allocate sparse array for result
    G = spalloc(length(data), length(nzeros), sum(nones));

    % Loop through pairs of zero crossings. Each pair gets a column in the
    % resultant matrix. The number of rows of the matrix is the number of 
    % samples. G(n, ii) ~= 0 indicates that sample n belongs to pair ii
    for ii = 1:min(length(nzeros), length(nones))
        sampleInd = nzeros(ii)+1:nzeros(ii)+nones(ii)-1;
        G(sampleInd, ii) = data(sampleInd);
    end

    % Sum the square root-compressed positive parts of signal between each zero
    % crossing
    height = sum(sqrt(G), 2);

    % Find the peak over average position
    [~, pos] = max(G, [], 2);

    out = zeros(size(data));
    out(pos) = height;
end
```

As I said, this is slow, and it only works for one channel at a time. The slow part is (unsurprisingly) the loop. If I change matrix G's allocation to the standard zeros(...) instead of a sparse array, the slow part then becomes the sum(...) and max(...) calculations, for obvious reasons.

How can I do this more efficiently? I am not averse to writing a MEX function, if that's what it'll take.

Comment: the processing you are doing looks suitable for a serial processing of the signal. I imagine this kind of serial processing is better done in C/C++ rather than in Matlab. Have you considered mex-ing this function?

Comment: If i understand correctly, sampleInd is a vector at each point in the loop. In this case you might be able to eliminate the loop if you use an index matrix rather than many vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now created a MEX function that performs the same task as the above code, apart from the last three lines, which need little modification to work with the MEX function. This method is orders of magnitude faster.

Here is the code, for reference:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

/*=======================
 * Output arguments
 *=======================
 */
#define OUT_zCross   plhs[0]
#define OUT_sums     plhs[1]
#define OUT_maxes    plhs[2]

/*=======================
 * Input arguments
 *=======================
 */
#define IN_x        prhs[0]
#define IN_fs       prhs[1]

#define myMax(x,y)     ( ( x ) > ( y ) ? ( x ) : ( y ) )

/*=======================
 * Main Function
 *=======================
 */
void mexFunction ( int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[] )
{
    /* params: signal vector; 
       outputs: indices (one-based) of the zero crossings,
       sum of positive values between each pair of zero crossings, and the indices
       (one-based) of the maximum element between each pair
    */

    double *x = NULL;
    double *zCross = NULL;
    double *sums = NULL;
    double *maxes = NULL;
    double curMax = 0;
    unsigned int curMaxPos = 0;
    int Fs = 0;
    unsigned int nZeroCrossings = 0;
    unsigned int nPeaks = 0;
    unsigned int nSamples = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0, t = 0;
    bool bIgnoreFirst = false;
    bool bSum = false;

    // Get signal and its size
    x = mxGetPr(IN_x);
    i = mxGetN (IN_x); 
    j = mxGetM (IN_x);

    if (i>1 && j>1) {
        mexPrintf ( "??? Input x must be a vector.\n" );
        return;
    }

    // Length of vector
    nSamples = myMax (i, j);

    zCross = mxCalloc(nSamples, sizeof(double));
    sums = mxCalloc(nSamples, sizeof(double));
    maxes = mxCalloc(nSamples, sizeof(double));

    if (x[0] > 0)
    {
        /* If the first sample is positive, we cannot generate a spike for the first
         pair of zero crossings as this represents part of the signal that is
         negative; therefore, skip the first zero crossing and begin pairing from
         the second */
        bIgnoreFirst = true;
    }
    else if (x[0] == 0)
    {
        // Begin summation from first element
        bSum = true;

        nZeroCrossings = 1;
        sums[0] = x[0];
        curMax = x[0];
        curMaxPos = 0;
    }

    for (t = 1; t < nSamples; ++t)
    {
        // Look for a zero-crossing
        if (x[t] * x[t-1] < 0 || (x[t] == 0 && x[t-1] != 0))
        {
            bool bIgnore = false;

            // If not the first one, we can safely flip the boolean flag
            if (nZeroCrossings != 0)
            {
                bSum = !bSum;
            }
            else if (!bIgnoreFirst)
            {
                // If not, make sure we're not supposed to ignore the first one
                bSum = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bIgnore = true;
            }

            // Store the zero-crossing index
            zCross[nZeroCrossings] = t+1;

            // If this crossing terminated the summation, store and reset the position of the max. element
            if (!bSum && !bIgnore)
            {
                maxes[nPeaks] = curMaxPos+1;
                curMax = 0;
                curMaxPos = 0;
                ++nPeaks;
            }

            ++nZeroCrossings;
        }

        if (bSum)
        {
            sums[nPeaks] += x[t];
            if (x[t] > curMax)
            {
                curMax = x[t];
                curMaxPos = t;
            }
        }
    }

    // Allocate outputs
    OUT_zCross = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    OUT_sums = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    OUT_maxes = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    mxSetPr(OUT_zCross, zCross);
    mxSetM(OUT_zCross, nZeroCrossings);
    mxSetN(OUT_zCross, 1);

    mxSetPr(OUT_sums, sums);
    mxSetM(OUT_sums, nPeaks);
    mxSetN(OUT_sums, 1);

    mxSetPr(OUT_maxes, maxes);
    mxSetM(OUT_maxes, nPeaks);
    mxSetN(OUT_maxes, 1);

    return;
}
```